# Network Name assigned to non-existent object

Tags: windows-10, powershell, network-adapter, windows-10-v1703

Tl;dr: I can't rename network adapters which were reset from the creators update, at least I think it was the creators update.

Following scenario: there is an image from an configured PC (IP adresses, j-frames and network adapter name were set) and after this image is put on another pc and the creators update is installed, the adapter names are reset and when I try to configure the old names, it says that the object already exists.
In the registry are no entrys with the network adapter (anymore, changed them to "ghost" for testing and made a restart).
Same Problem as [here (Link)](https://superuser.com/questions/1127645/ip-address-assigned-to-non-existent-adapter) only that the part with the Network name didn't work for me.

I use the following command with admin rights in the windows powershell:

```
Rename-NetAdapter -InterfaceAlias "OLD_NAME" -NewName "NEW_NAME"
```

But I get the following Error:

```
Rename-NetAdapter : {Object Exists} An attempt was made to create an object and the object name already existed. 
At line:1 char:1
+ Rename-NetAdapter -InterfaceAlias "OLD_NAME" -NewName "NEW_NAME"
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        + CategoryInfo          : ResourceExists: (MSFT_NetAdapter...= "DOMAIN"):ROOT/StandardCimv2/MSFT_NetAdapter) [ 
       Rename-NetAdapter], CimException
        + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Windows System Error 698,Rename-NetAdapter
```

And a manual configuration fails too.

I can rename the Adapter to an other name, only "NEW_NAME" fails. This was the name of an adapter that was present before the creators update.

The system is a windows 10 64bit OS with v 1703 (creators update).

My question is: How can I assign "NEW_NAME" again to the network adapter?

Comment: Have you tried completely resetting your networking in Windows? Search `reset network` on Start. FYI: This will delete *all* network-related configuration, including things like saved WiFi passwords.

Comment: Tried it just now, same result. The "NEW_NAME" is still in use.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar (but not exact) issue in the past.

Please be **very** careful editing the registry.

If you open up the registry editor and go to `Computer` > `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` > `System` > `CurrentControlSet` > `Control` > `Network`.

Firstly, right click and export to take a backup of this entire key.

Next, expand each of the GUID names and the `Connection` keys until you find the name you were trying to rename to.

Once you find it, try to simply rename the registry value to something else (write old at the end for example) and restart your computer.

If this doesn't help, instead go up a level to the GUID key itself and right click, then delete. Restart your computer again and see if you can now do what you want.

Comment: Hello William,
Yes I already made an attempt in this direction. After renaming one entry with the name after another and restarting in between, I began to delete the entries without any success.
Right now my registry has no entries with "NEW_NAME" but when i try to change an adapter name to "NEW_NAME" it says that the name is already assigned.

Comment: can yuo try going in to registry editor and click search, then try to find if anything else has the name? Also, possibly try using this tool - http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/device_manager_view.html - it will allow you to see disconnected devices and jump to the registry to delete (I've not tried disable in the app)

Comment: Yes, there are few other entries with the "NEW_NAME". I changed every occurence with "NEW_NAME" to "GHOST" (dummy name) and restarted.
No success. The "NEW_NAME" is bound to an inteface which is not connected to the PC.
So I tried deleting all entries i find which have a relation with "NEW_NAME" and the interface -> Reboot -> problem is still there.